# TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, conditional-statements, typeerror

The Goal: Similar to the first project, this project also uses the random module in Python. The program will first randomly generate a number unknown to the user. The user needs to guess what that number is. (In other words, the user needs to be able to input information.) If the user’s guess is wrong, the program should return some sort of indication as to how wrong (e.g. The number is too high or too low). If the user guesses correctly, a positive indication should appear. You’ll need functions to check if the user input is an actual number, to see the difference between the inputted number and the randomly generated numbers, and to then compare the numbers.

And this is what i did but i dont know how to fix it:

[image]

Comment: You went to the effort of taking a screenshot, saving the file to disk and uploading it, when copy/paste your code into SO takes about half a second? It's dedicated, but it makes things harder for us :(

Comment: Some logical problem in your code, it generates a new random number every time the user makes a guess. This could lead to "guess 4, too high, guess 3, too low, lol whut??"

Comment: ok thx i will look into it

Comment: I note that your code doesn't really have any comments. All your life you've been learning to think in English, but now you're learning a new language, it would be best to first sketch out the algorithm in a language you're familiar with. I.e first think it through in English, then translate to python. Don't try and do the two steps simultaneously

Comment: Thx I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3, `input` returns a string. You pass this string to your function directly and compare with integers obtained from `random.choice`. This is what happens:

```
In [535]: '1' > 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-535-6857a5c3feea> in <module>()
----> 1 '1' > 2

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Conclusion: `int`s and `str`ings are not comparable. You'll need to convert the input by calling the `int` function.

```
your_guess = int(input(...))
```

And then, it should work:

```
In [536]: 1 > 2
Out[536]: False
```

---

However, this solves only one problem. Every time you call your function, `number` is re-initialised with a new value each time, so that if you guess against a number and call the function again, you will be guessing against a totally different random number next time. You'll want to set `numbers` *outside* the function and *then* call the function, passing the guess and random number as arguments.